# Live agent pre chat custom detail

Tags: liveagent, pre-chat

I'm trying to push some custom data to the chat console from pre chat from but without success. I've tried hidden form elements like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat:Username" value="Anonymous" />
```

And also tried JavaScript API

```
liveagent.addCustomDetail('Username', "Anonymous", true);
```

But the agent sees only most recently viewed pages when hovering over "Accept" chat button. Also no custom variables are displayed after chat is initialized.

The pre-chat form is embedded on a client site. To submit the form I just use this code:

```
<a href="javascript://Chat" onClick="liveagent.startChat('XXXX')">START CHAT</a>
```

How can I debug this? What is the correct way to pass this custom data?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the deployment API which is different to the tags that must be used in the pre-chat form.

Here is an example on how to create a case with some information pre-populated that will also show in the console for the agent, you can do the same without creating a record, this should give you an idea.

```
<input type='hidden' name='liveagent.prechat:caseorigin' value='Chat'/>
<input type='hidden' name='liveagent.prechat:caseContactId' value='{!$User.ContactId}'/>
<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map:Case" value="Origin,caseorigin;ContactId,caseContactId;" />
<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map.doCreate:Case" value="Origin,true;ContactId,true;" />
<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.saveToTranscript:Case" value="Case" />
<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.showOnCreate:Case" value="true" />
```

The section you care about if all you want is to show the details on the console would be this

```
<input type='hidden' name='liveagent.prechat:caseContactId' value='{!$User.ContactId}'/>
```

in combination with this value

```
<input type= "hidden" name= "liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.displayToAgent:caseContactId" value= "true" />
```

With that, you are assigning a value to a custom chat detail that will be shown to the agent that gets the chat assigned.

Comment: But all I want to do is to push some custom data that does not exists in salesforce and if I do something like this: `<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat:Balance" value="123" />` I don't get anything in the console.

Comment: I have updated the answer, if you are not finding or creating you need to also use the displayToAgent method.

Comment: But what you wrote (two hidden input fields `liveagent.prechat:caseContactId` and `liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.displayToAgent:caseContactId`) is essentially the same as using JavaScript API and calling `liveagent.addCustomDetail('Username', "Anonymous", true);`, right? At least that's what I've found in [the docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.live_agent_dev.meta/live_agent_dev/live_agent_customizing_visitor_details_API_addCustomDetail.htm). The problem is that neither of those works for me. My console does not get any additional data.

Comment: They do the same but in a different way. I have successfully used the deployment API  method as well. Can you post the entire relevant code?

Comment: I've inherited some gibberish code from other dev and I'm now trying to clean it up. My eyes hurt when I stare at it if you know what I mean :) The weird thing is that after some tweaking to the code I was able make this work **only** with JavaScript API, but HTML with those hidden elements still doesn't work. Unfortunately these changes caused another issue with [liveagent.init()](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/49436/wait-until-liveagent-init-finishes)