# Wait until liveagent.init() finishes

Tags: liveagent, pre-chat

It looks like the `init()` function is asynchronous - is there any way to know when it finishes? Something like jQuery `complete`? For example

```
.getJSON('/blah', function(data) {
  /* Invoked when request finishes */
});
```

The problem that I'm facing is that if I call `liveagent.startChat()` immediately after `liveagent.init()` I get parse error inside `deplyment.js` script:

```
TypeError: l[a] is undefined
  ...on(){aa()};n.startChat=function(a,b,c){(b?K(a,b):l[a]).startChat("liveagent"+Mat...

deployment.js (line 63, col 336)
```

But if I wait a while  before calling `liveagent.startChat()` then everything works fine.

Comment: There is no callback like getJSON has, however if you have a Start Chat button you can watch for it to go "online", at that point liveagent is finished loading.

Comment: @ScottW Sorry for the late response but I did something similar and used hidden div to watch for 'online' status. If you'll turn your comment into an answer I'll be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just in case someone else comes across this. We have an article that explains how to handle this

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Live-Agent-Starting-a-chat-ends-with-a-404-page&language=en_US

Sample Code:

```
<div id="chatonline" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (!window._laq) { window._laq = []; }
    window._laq.push(function(){
        liveagent.showWhenOnline('573i0000000B238', document.getElementById('chatonline'));
    });
</script>

<script type='text/javascript' src='https://c.la1a1.salesforceliveagent.com/content/g/js/36.0/deployment.js'></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>

    liveagent.addButtonEventHandler('573i0000000B238',function (e){
        if(e == liveagent.BUTTON_EVENT.BUTTON_AVAILABLE){              
            liveagent.startChatWithWindow('573i0000000B238','mywindowid');          
        }       
    });
    liveagent.init('https://c.la1a1.salesforceliveagent.com/chat', '572i0000000AybE', '00Di0000000jR2X');
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks @PeppeFloyd. I'm accepting this answer, however I said farewell to the salesforce chat months ago and suggest the same to anyone struggling with it. It's just not worth it. Use proper chat solutions like livechatinc.com and others - they can integrate with salesforce anyway.